# Protobufs Timestamp as RFC 3339 string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, protocol-buffers

I currently have two applications, which communicate with each other using a REST API. The first is a .NET 7 Web API project and the second is a Java desktop app which uses an HTTP Client to connect to the API.

In the current implementation I am forced to write all of the REST models as both Java classes and C# classes, which is a little cumbersome.

I have done some looking into Protobufs, and I believe that I can leverage its compiler to do this class creation for me. Instead of writing language specific classes I would instead write a `.proto` file and compile it to create the classes. It's worth reiterating that neither of the applications use gRPC, just REST.

One file in my solution allows a user to search for events within a specified date range:

```
message SearchParameters {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp date_range_start = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp date_range_end = 2;
}
```

Previously this worked by passing two dates to the API in RFC 3339 format (e.g. `2020-12-09T16:09:53Z`), however now that I have introduced Protobufs my API is expecting the dates to be in the format:

```
{
  "seconds": 11223344,
  "nanos": 0
}
```

I would like to continue to pass dates in as RFC 3339 strings, as opposed to to `seconds`/`nanos`.

I have tried to add a `JsonConverter` to the C# project, but it had some issues with the dates getting wrapped in an extra set of quotes (i.e. `"\"2020-12-09T16:09:53Z\""`), and it only "fixed" the return types, if I passed dates in RFC 3339 format they would end up as `null`.

Additionally there are indications in the Protobufs documentation that the expected behaviour is for RFC 3339 format to be used when mapping to JSON:

> In JSON format, the Timestamp type is encoded as a string in the RFC 3339 format.

Refs:

- https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-dlp-v2/latest/Google-Protobuf-Timestamp
- https://protobuf.dev/reference/java/api-docs/com/google/protobuf/Timestamp
- https://protobuf.dev/reference/php/api-docs/Google/Protobuf/Timestamp

Because of this I am not really sure that writing a `JsonConverter` is the correct approach.

Is there some way to make Protobuf Timestampss work like I want, or is there perhaps an alternative to either Timestamps, or Protobuf itself that would solve the issue of sharing REST API models between languages

Comment: From what I understand from your question, I'd encourage you to reconsider using Protobufs.

Comment: First, if you're using REST, you may want to consider e.g. [OpenAPI](https://openapi-generator.tech/). This is a tool that allows you to generate language bindings for .NET, Java and many others from a schema that you define that represents  a REST API. It will also generate API documentation too.

Comment: Second, you appear to only want to use Protobufs for the code-generation. The best practice is that you should not use the types generated by Protobuf in its stubs in your application code but you should (continue to use) application-specific classes and maps these to the Protobuf generated "stubs".

Comment: I use gRPC and protobufs in my own development and am a proponent of these technologies but, it seems that, by trying to adopt protobufs in this way, you're adding complexity (and problems) for naught.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for taking the time to respond. I will look into OpenAPI, I selected Protobufs as it integrated into my project without too much hassle (until I ran into the JSON serialisation issue), so it seemed like it would be an easy solution, but if there is something better available I don't mind switching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve my issue by creating a `TypeConverter`, to convert the RFC 3339 string to a `Timestamp`.

Using a `TypeConverter` was much more versatile than a custom Model Binder, as it only needed to be defined once, rather than manually specifying the custom model binder any time I used a `Timestamp` in my API.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Timestamp), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(TimestampTypeConverter)));
```

```
public class TimestampTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, System.Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object? ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object value)
    {
        return Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()!, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should expect to run into more problems if you're just special-casing Timestamp. There may be various other places where the Protobuf JSON representation doesn't behave in exactly the same way as Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json. If "the other end" is either serializing or deserializing from protos, you should really use the same mechanism in your code, or you'll end up with hard-to-debug issues.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're just using the default JSON serialization with System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json. I'd advise you *not* to do that with protobuf messages, which have their own JSON representation.

Instead, assuming you're using Google.Protobuf, either just call `ToString()` on the message and you'll get a JSON representation, or use [`JsonFormatter`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/csharp/api-docs/class/google/protobuf/json-formatter.html) - you can create different instances of `JsonFormatter` based on any formatting options you want.

Likewise, when parsing, just use [`JsonParser`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/csharp/api-docs/class/google/protobuf/json-parser.html) - or the `ParseJson` method on `MessageParser<T>`, e.g. `SearchParameters.Parser.ParseJson(json)`.

Comment: This is likely correct, I am using the built in Model Binding [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0] to convert the JSON request into the Model created by Protobuf, and then returning an object from the controller method and letting .NET convert it (presumably using System.Text.Json). Does this mean that I have to manually parse the request/response in every controller method? Or is there some way to get the built in Model Binder to use the JsonFormatter/JsonParser

Comment: @Campbell: That I don't know, I'm afraid. I'd expect there to be some way to configure the model binder, but it's not something I've done. Remember that the generated C# code uses partial classes, so you should be able to use `ModelBinderAttribute` or `IModelBinderProvider` in a handwritten partial class to specify the binder to use.